# 'WADE' in water - how deep can you wade? ankle-, knee-, waist, neck-deep?

Tags: meaning

There seems to be a difference of opinion on the WWW about the meaning of 'wade', varying from ankle to neck deep. Some say only walking in ankle-deep water is considered wading, others seem to think you're wading until you're neck-deep in the water.

And if you're wading only until you're ankle, knee, or waist deep, then what do you call walking in the water that is higher than that?

Comment: Requests for opinions are frowned on here in ELL.  And what research have you done? *Merriam-Webster* defines the intransitive *wade* as “to step in or through a medium (such as water) offering more resistance than air.”

Comment: I would agree with @PaulTanenbaum here that this is an opinion question more than a language one. Each native speaker might have a different opinion of this, and it's usage in English is going to reflect that. If you have a question that relates more directly to the language and could have a correct answer, you could edit your question to focus on that.

Comment: It also depends on what equipment you are using. in walking boots you could wade through 1 or 2 inches of water, in wellington boots 6-9 inches in special boots/trousers called "waders" you could get up to thigh high in some designs and chest high in others. Then, if you didn't mind getting wet, you could wade through anything where you could keep your feet on the ground and your face above the surface.

Comment: You can easily find occurrences of 'waded up to his neck' by Googling. Often news stories about accidents or rescues. Any deeper and one would drown.

Comment: I have removed the sentence requesting opinion. Without it, I think it stands as a question about the meaning(s) of the verb "wade".

Comment: My 2 cents as an American: it makes sense up to "chest," but any more than that I'd think twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english), Wading means walking in water that is deep enough to require some effort to walk through. Water that only comes up to my ankles is probably not deep enough to be considered "wading".  Provided that you are walking (and not swimming or submerged) it can be called wading.

British English uses "wade" figuratively to mean "do something with difficulty", eg "I had to wade through 500 pages of legal reports before I found the case I was looking for".

In [american-english](/questions/tagged/american-english) it tends to be used for shallower water, and in situations that British English speakers call "paddling".  There is quite a lot of overlap between the American and British uses of the word: "They waded across the stream" would correct in both dialects.

Comment: Note that neck would likely be too deep, at that point the water is providing enough buoyancy it would be swimming. I've never tested this in a rigorous way but I suspect about nipple-deep would be the limit of wading.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, that depends on the density (or specific gravity) of one’s body. Some of us have so little body fat that we tend to sink.

Answer (score 2):

To complement James K's answer, you asked what term to use when the water level is higher than wading level.

I don't know of any other term that means to walk through water, so if the water level were higher than wading, it's just "*walking through water*", possibly including some expression about the height of the water, like "*at chest height*",  "*at waist level*" or "*knee deep*".

If it's above your head and you're still walking, then it's "*walking underwater*" or "*walking on the ocean floor/the bottom of the lake*".

Comment: I (British English speaker) would call it wading as long as your feet can still touch the bottom! Another instance of 'divided by a common language'?

Comment: @KateBunting To be clear, do you mean you'd still call it wading if you were walking fully underwater, say in the deep end of a pool?

Comment: No, I meant 'as long as your feet can touch the bottom _while at least your head is above the water_', i.e. before you have to start swimming.

Comment: @KateBunting Me too. In my answer I'm allowing for other people who think "wade" stops at a level of water lower than the head, as it seems there are many from the comments and James's answer.